# PrettyFaces: @URLQueryParameter is not passed to @URLAction method

Tags: prettyfaces

I can't figure out how to pass a parameter from an URL to a specified controller method.
So here is how I annotated the controller:

```
@Component
@ManagedBean
@RequestScoped
@URLMappings(mappings={
        @URLMapping(id = "posts", pattern = "/posts/", viewId = "/faces/posts/list.xhtml"),
        @URLMapping(id = "postComments", pattern = "/posts/#{id}/comments", viewId = "/faces/posts/post_comments.xhtml")
})
public class PostsController {

  @Autowired
  private PostService postService;

  private Post post;

  @URLQueryParameter("id")
  private String id;

  public Post getPost() {        
    return postService.findById(Long.valueOf(getId()));
  }

  @URLAction(mappingId = "postsComments")
  public void loadPost() {
    System.out.println("in loadPost, ID: " + getId());
  }
}
```

And here is the view:

```
<ui:repeat value="#{postsController.posts}" var="post">
                    <tr>
                        <td>#{post.title}</td>
                        <td>
                            <pretty:link mappingId="postComments">
                                <f:param value="#{post.id}" />
                                Comments
                            </pretty:link>
                        </td>
                        <td><a href="#">Edit</a></td>
                        <td><a href="#">Delete</a></td>
                    </tr>
                </ui:repeat>
```

And my id is always null. Nevertheless, in the generated HTML code the id is always correct:

```
posts/1/comments
posts/2/comments
posts/3/comments
```

etc.

Any idea? I'm using PrettuFaces 3.3.3.
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You could get your `id` parameter in the `getPost()` method with :
`FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getRequestParameterMap().get("id")`